# Crontab : Permission denied

Tags: crontab

My crontab (running as user) contains the following command

```
00-59 00-23 * * *  /usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data -u USER -p PASSWORD
```

But I am getting an error as

> You don't have enough permissions to access `smb://192.168.10.32/Data/`

But the same command I **can** execute (running as user) from command line.

How to give permissions to crontab to solve the issue?

Comment: maybe you should ask on serverfault.com

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and it took me about 6 hours to work out the answer. You get it for free:

When you are logged in properly, you will have an environment variable USER=root - this will not be in your environment when you run a job from crontab.

To set an environment variable for one command in crontab, simply put it directly before your command (i.e. after the time/day specification). So in your case:

```
00-59 00-23 * * *  USER=root /usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data -u USER -p PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 3):

I would set up Autofs to take care of mounting the SMB file system. You can use a credentials file to keep it a bit more secure. From there, your cronjob is simply cp /mnt/smbshare/data /home/whomever/whereever.

Autofs won't leave the SMB share mounted forever, and it will help you eliminate the hassle of trying to figure out those SMB tools inside cron.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs